# how to save own function for repetitive use

Tags: python-3.x

I want to use my own function in different code,every time i have to copy function and paste in new code,So i want to save function permanently,then i can access my own function in different code with single line function access.like we are using sum(),mean() function in same way want to use my own function.please help

```
def get_dataframe(list2):
    wpr_day=[]
    for i in range(len(list2)):
       with open(list2[i], 'r') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')  
            for row in reader:
               if len(row) == 0:
                      continue
               wpr_day.append(row)
    for row1 in aa:
    cols1=row1.split()
    if(cols1[0]=='Date'):
        date8.append(a[0])
        for i in range(int(bins)):
            dlist.append(aa[line_no])           
    elif(cols1[0]=='Time'):
        time8.append(aa[line_no][7:15])
        for i in range(int(bins)):
            tlist.append(aa[line_no][7:15])       
    elif(cols1[0]=='Height(mtr)'):
        blist.append((wpr_day))
        fd=fd.append(wpr_day.iloc[(line_no+1):(line_no+(int(bins)+1)),:])
    elif(cols1[0]=='Height'):
        for v in range(line_no+1,line_no+(int(bins)+1)):
            df_ht.append(aa[v])
            df_snr.append(bb[v])
    line_no=line_no+1   

return result_df,dtime_uvw,date8,blist,df_ht,df_snr
```

i want to use my own function in different code with single line access
example,
 result_df_slp,dtime_uvw_slp,date8_slp,blist_slp,xx,yy=get_dataframe(list_uvw1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can just put it in a file, like gd.py, and then in the program that wants it put at the top:

```
from gd.py import get_dataframe
```

You may have to change this depending on where you locate the file. There is a lot of good information about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder).

Comment: can u explain more about gd.py,

Comment: What I was saying was that you can create gd.py containing your python code for the function get_dataframe, then import that function from that file into any other python program.